# Use of CheckedChanged using Windows Forms and Powershell assistance

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm using WinForms with PowerShell.  In my tool, I'd like a checkbox that when checked, will display a message next to it, and when unchecked, it will remove the message.

I've gotten this far (I'm sure there's a much better way to do it).  This makes the message pop-up, but it doesn't go away when you uncheck the box.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
$Checkbox_Errors.Add_CheckStateChanged({   ### Checkbox_Errors is the name of the checkbox
if ($Checkbox_Errors.Checked -eq $true)
{
$ErrorWarning1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ErrorWarning1.Text = "WARNING: May take 3-5 Minutes"  ### When checked, this is what it should display
$ErrorWarning1.ForeColor = "Red"
$ErrorWarning1.AutoSize = $True
$ErrorWarning1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(170,13)
$groupbox.Controls.Add($ErrorWarning1)
}

})


$Checkbox_Errors.Add_CheckStateChanged({
if ($Checkbox_Errors.Unchecked -eq $true)
{
$ErrorWarning1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ErrorWarning1.Text = "" ### I attempted this, where it would re-write
$ErrorWarning1.ForeColor = "Red"
$ErrorWarning1.AutoSize = $True
$ErrorWarning1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(170,13)
$groupbox.Controls.Add($ErrorWarning1)
}

})
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to create the label with the rest of your form elements. If you're using a designer, you can just drag it on with the rest of the controls. Then set the label's Visible property to $False initially to hide it.

```
$ErrorWarning1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$ErrorWarning1.Text = "WARNING: May take 3-5 Minutes"
$ErrorWarning1.ForeColor = "Red"
$ErrorWarning1.AutoSize = $True
$ErrorWarning1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Point(170,13)
$ErrorWarning1.Visible = $False # This line hides the label initially
$groupbox.Controls.Add($ErrorWarning1)
```

Now in your event handler, instead of generating the label, just show or hide it based on the state of the checkbox:

```
$ErrorWarning1.Visible = $Checkbox_Errors.Checked
```

The label will always exist, but it will only be visible when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That definitely seems like a more elegant way of handling it.  Now I just have to figure out what my "event handler" is.  Time to go learn.

Comment: No problem. Here your event handler is `Add_CheckStateChanged`. Just replace everything between the braces with the last line of code in my answer. It should look like this: `$Checkbox_Errors.Add_CheckStateChanged({ $ErrorWarning1.Visible = $Checkbox_Errors.Checked })`.